# RxJS Detect When Subscription has Closed

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, rxjs5

Is there a way to detect when a Subscription has closed?  I have a loading component that displays a loading message when a Subscription exists && is not closed, and otherwise displays the content, but once closed I wanted to reset the variable that was referencing the subscription, otherwise I can't use `mySubscription.closed` as an useful indicating in the template.

Comment: By 'closed' I'm guessing that you mean 'has no subscribers'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, based on the [RxJS subscribe() documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) there are 3 arguments that can be passed, last one being the OnCompleted callback.

```
var observer = Rx.Observer.create(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: %s', x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: %s', err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple other options.

#### [`tap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) and [`finalize()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/finalize)

These are both operators that you put in a `pipe(...)` - so the logic runs independent of the `subscribe(...)` call which you may not even be in your control.

> [`finalize()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/finalize) is called on `completion` OR `error`
>
> [`tap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) has three parameters `next`, `error`, and `complete` that are called on those conditions

Finalize should probably be reserved for true cleanup type tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribe()` method accepts three functions as parameters (arguments). The function supplied as the last parameter is called when the subscription is closed.

```
YourObservable.subscribe(
value => console.log('This is called every time when observable emits'),
error => console.log('This is called when error occurs'), 
() => console.log('This is called when subscription closed')
);
```

Comment: What if you don't have access to the `subscribe` method?  I have a reference to the `Subscription`, but I'm in a child component that uses it to display a loading message so only access to the properties of the Subscription like `mySubscription.closed`

Comment: That means you don't have access to your observable?

Comment: No access to the observable.  Basically the code does `this.busy = this.http.get(...);` and then `busy` is passed to the loading component, which uses `busy && !busy.closed` to display the loading message and disappears after `closed`, which works in 90% of our cases.

Comment: http.get returns an observable, here 'busy' is your observable. isn't it?